# Email notification based on purchased item

Tags: 7, ubercart, emails, notifications

I am working on the magazine site using Ubercart. In this site individual magazines can be bought or subscribed to. When a new issue of a magazine which the customer has subscribed to is created, I need to send a notification to all the customers who have subscribed to that magazine.

Can I achieve this using the messaging and notification module? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rules? The trigger would be when new content is added, and the condition would be that the content type is appropriate. Not sure how you've stored the data connecting subscribers to their magazine, but that will be needed for the action. I *don't think* you'll be able to do this out of the box (specifically I'm not sure if you can send an email to multiple addresses using rules) - so you might need to [write a custom action](http://drupal.org/node/172152).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I m also thinking about using rules but I didn't find the conditions I need to use. Is there also a way to write custom conditions in rule. First of all I need to retrieve all customer who have bought the subscription of particular magazine. How Can I do that?

Comment: @Dipesh How have you currently set things up? How are you storing this data?

Comment: @Andy: Thanks.I didn't understand before. Now I think I need to write a custom action. For this site I set the product type as magazine. So the condition could be when the user creates a node of type magazine. I created the term for different magazine. So, in action First I need to retrieve the term associated with created node, then I need to find all the purchase of subscription and related customer from order. After that I need to send the email to the customer by retrieving its email. Can you guide little more about how should I write code? In drupal how to send mail writing code?

Comment: @Dipesh Sorry for the delay, been a bit busy. How do users subscribe to a magazine?

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for showing the way. I solved it by writing the sql query in the custom action and for mail I used the drupal_mail there. Now I m checking whether it works properly or not. Is drupal_mail good for sending a lot of email at a time? Since as the customer in the site increases no. of email to send also increases.

Comment: @Dipesh great! If you have a lot of emails to send it might be an idea to use [Queue Mail](http://drupal.org/project/queue_mail) or [MailQ](http://drupal.org/project/mailq)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) module. It allows users to subscribe and also unsubscribe (usefull feature) to your mass mailing. You can also setup multiple mass mailing. You can also mass mail everyone on your site.

Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The notify module allows users to subscribe to periodic emails which include all new or revised content and/or comments of specific content types, much like the daily newsletters sent by some websites.
>
> Even if this feature is not configured for normal site users, it can be a useful feature for an administrator of a site to receive notification of new content submissions and comment posts.
>
> The notifications are sent out in batches (digest style) at a frequency determined by the administrator. The administrator also decides what content type(s) to make available for notification subscriptions.
>
> In the Drupal 7 version, ordinary users can turn notifications on and off, whether to receive just headlines, teasers, or complete nodes/comments, and what content types to subscribe to. (The Drupal 6 version only offer some of these options.)

Comment: Is there any way to add conditions on who gets the mail? I researched about messaging and notification module and I found that it doesn't support the conditions and notify module also seems doesn't support the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Who Bought What|Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_who_bought_what) module can be useful for your case.

> This is for Ubercart. If you are using Ubercart to sell tickets or entries to an event or perhaps a race, it's very helpful to have a list, per item, of who bought what. For a competition, this will become an entry list. For a performance, this may become your will-call attendance list.

The Drupal 8 version has been created as separate project: [Who Bought What (Ubercart)](https://www.drupal.org/project/who_bought_what).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked that module earlier. It gives all the email list of the user how bought a particular product. which is what I wanted. but If I use this module I need to select the product and send email manually. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

@Andy

I am using [Commerce Invoice/Reciept][1] module.

with a php code in main template file **commerce-order-invoice-view.tpl.php** something like below :

```
   $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $order->commerce_line_items['und'][0]["line_item_id"]);
   $product_sku = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->sku->value();

    if($product_sku =="ONCE_OFF")
    {
      include 'commerce-order-invoice-once-off.php';
    }
    else
    {
      include 'commerce-order-invoice-recurring.php';
    }
```

After that you can create new files for emails.
FYI : $order object will be available in both files.

Hope this helps.

```
  [1]: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice_receipt
```